# How to pass HTML Text Item to Ruby

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have one variable on a HTML page say FIRSTNAME.

The user would enter a value here, which RUBY would SELECT and DISPLAY on the browser.

Rather a trivial problem but I am not able to crack it.

I am passing the HTML variable in FORM ACTION as `<%= edit_rockbook_path %>`. But the problem in HTML everything is treated as string, so how to pass values of firstname.

Here is the code:

```
<body>
<FORM ACTION='<%=edit_rockbook_path ("firstname")%>'; >
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" />
<INPUT type="submit" value="Hello world!" >
<br/>
</FORM>
</body>
```

Comment: I assume this is Ruby on Rails, please replace the tag if I'm wrong.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure to understand the question… Which is your ruby variable? firstname? If yes, and if it has been set in the controller, it should be an instance variable: @firstname.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems going on in your code, one of them being that it appears that you are hand coding your form. I would recommend that you step back and do some reading about [Resource Oriented Architecture](http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=resource+oriented+architecture&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). ROA is an important concept for understanding Rails and how it works with forms.

Once you get the concept of a resource then you are ready to play with the scaffold generator:

```
rails generate scaffold some_resource resource_attribute1 resource_attribute2
```

So for example:

```
rails generate scaffold home address zipcode
```

This will create an entry in your config/routes.rb, a controller, some views, a model and a database migration that will create for your database. READ ALL THOSE FILES. They are good examples of best(or at least good) practices for Rails applications. Run

```
rake routes
```

and read about routing in Rails so you understand what the output means.

You will notice in scaffold generated files that they are using a helper method called form_for. You should be using that, but switching to it without understanding the other stuff won't help you much.

Also checkout the guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/
And http://railscasts.com/ and http://peepcode.com/

I hope that helps!

Comment: Actually, I passed thru all those steps.

Comment: Actually, I passed thru all these steps. The application is GENERATEd by the RAILS script only using SCAFFOLDING etc. I just want to modify the default behaviour a bit. The code runs well when I am hardcoding the ID number I want to see. <body>
<FORM ACTION="<%=edit_rockbook_path(1)%>">
First name: <input type="text" name="id" />
<INPUT type="submit" value="Hello world!" >
<br/>
</FORM>
</body>

Comment: My requirement is more database intensive. It cannot be done by the default behaviour of MVC generated code. I want to display only those records which the user enters in TEXT box. Thanks for the help.